# How to preview word files through documents portlet like pdf files?

Tags: liferay, portlet, docx

I have added the document portlet and to that a few pdf's and word files.
But when I  click on pdf files they generate a preview, and the docx files don't. Why?

I want to preview the docx files also. Is there a method to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay makes use of OpenOffice/LibreOffice for deciphering MS-Office documents. You'll have to set up [a connection to OpenOffice or LibreOffice](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/server-administration#openofficelibreoffice-configuration) (which has to run in server mode) in order to use it the way you want.

Comment: I am not able to download OpenOffice.. Can you pls suggest a site where i can download it?

Comment: ...and you expect me (or anybody here) to do what with this nonexistent error message? Come on: If you literally say "Something doesn't work", I'd say "Do something different". If you're more specific, I can be more specific as well.

Comment: i downloaded openoffice.. installed.. i added the contents in portal-ext.properties file. i used this cmd:" soffice --headless --accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;"
--nofirststartwizard" , but the nect command was: 'soffice' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: "soffice" is the name of the executable file which you'll find within your OpenOffice installation. If it's been renamed since it's been documented for Liferay, you'll have to use its current name. (the "s" goes back to the former parent project, "Star Office"). You seem to be on Windows and as long as OpenOffice is not on the path, you'll have to explicitly state the directory that the executable is located in.